# Why 'battery storage power stations' use mainly liion batteries?

Tags: power, battery, electrical-grid

As I understand liion batteries have lower lifetime, than LiFePO4. Why would such big stations use liion batteries then? Wouldn't replacement cost large amount of money? And how long those liion battery storage power stations last, before batteries are no longer usable?

Comment: Better capacity and factored with cost...

Comment: They are mostly used for short duration, high current applications. Lion has a higher specific power than LiFePO4, so you need less of them for a given trim power.

Comment: Much on web on this. LiIon cells can have large cycle lives if used conservatively. Mars Rovers get around 8000 cycles. 2000 not too hard with due care. LiFePO4 has superior cycle life. Whole of life Ah saved and returned per all up $ is the likely metric and apparently LiIon offers this.

Comment: You must also factor in when each one came to market.